djl does not use the installed gpu
I tested dji in jupyter notebook and java. I tested it with mxnet and tensorflow. In all tests i am not able to get djl to use the gpu.
java: jdk 11, python 13.3, pip 24.3.1
Here the java src:
Engine.debugEnvironment();
System.out.println(Engine.getAllEngines());
for (Device d : Engine.getInstance().getDevices())
    System.out.println(d.toString());
System.out.println(Engine.getInstance().getGpuCount());
NDManager manager = NDManager.newBaseManager();
var x = manager.arange(12);
System.out.println(x.getDevice());

dependencies:


  <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ai.djl</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.31.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ai.djl.tensorflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>tensorflow-engine</artifactId>
    <version>0.31.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ai.djl.tensorflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>tensorflow-native-cu121</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.1</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>



here the output (private data removed)
------------------ CUDA -----------------<br/>
GPU Count: 1<br/>
CUDA: 121<br/>
ARCH: 52<br/>
GPU(0) memory used: 732679372 bytes<br/>
<br/>
----------------- Engines ---------------<br/>
DJL version: 0.31.0<br/>
2024-11-30 07:14:49.458693: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.<br/>
2024-11-30 07:14:49.517657: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.<br/>
To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.<br/>
Default Engine: TensorFlow:2.16.1, capabilities: [<br/>
    MKL,<br/>
]<br/>
TensorFlow Library: C:\Users\test\.djl.ai\tensorflow\2.16.1-cpu-win-x86_64\jnitensorflow.dll<br/>
Default Device: cpu()<br/>
TensorFlow: 3<br/>
[TensorFlow]<br/>
cpu()<br/>
0<br/>
ND: (12) cpu() int32<br/>
[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

